# Why does this JavaScript validation work depending on the order of conditions?

Tags: javascript, validation, conditional-statements

I am writing one small function which validates one text, and I am very upset because of the validation.

The problem is: when I try to compare the string to null (to check the cancel button), it works depending on where I put the condition! It seems to be working only when I put at the beginning of the validation. I have tested it with parenthesis for each condition too, but I get the same result.

What´s happening here?

I found this answer on Stack Overflow, but it is for Python and I don´t understand it very well:

*[Does the Order of Conditions affect Performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39946279/does-the-order-of-conditions-affect-performance)*

#### Code

```
function validate()
{
    var isValid = false;

    var text;

    while (isValid == false)
    {
        text = prompt("Enter one text between 1 and 10 characters, no empty, blank spaces, only numbers");

        /*
          WITH NULL (CANCEL BUTTON) VALIDATION AT THE BEGINNING,
          IT WORKS:
        */

        if (text != null &&
            (text.length >= 1 && text.length <= 10) &&
            text != "" &&
            isNaN(text) == false)
        {
            isValid=true;
        }

        /*
          WITH NULL (CANCEL BUTTON) VALIDATION AT ANOTHER POSITION, IT DOESN´T WORK:

          It generates "TypeError:Text is null"
        */

        if ( (text.length >= 1 && text.length < 10)  &&
             isNaN(text) == false && text != "" && text !=null)
        {
              isValid = true;
        }
    }

    if (isValid == true)
    {
        // Some code when validation is OK
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because let's say that we had the following values:

```
var text = 'Tim is an alright person',
    notText = null
```

If we try to access a property of `notText`, we will get an error because `null` doesn't have a properties like `length`. So, in code:

```
if(text.length){...}
```

works because `text` has a `length` property. However, the following does not work:

```
if(notText.length){...}
```

because notText does *not* have a length property. It will throw the error of TypeError because you are trying to do something with the `null` type that is not allowed.

So, we need the `text != null` check first because it will fail early, before trying the other expressions.

Comment: What a great explanation! Now I get it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You want to check if the text is not null first, because if that condition fails, the rest of the conditions will not be evaluated, since the && invariant has been violated.  If the text is null, and the null check comes after some other check, you will receive an error.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words:

If you evaluate `text.anyproperty == null` you're asking if the `anyproperty` of the var `text` is `null`, but this way you are taking for granted that `text` is not `null`, which will fail with the error you mentioned (TypeError) if `text` is actually `null`.

In order to avoid this pitfall you must ask first for `text` and then for `text.anyproperty` like this: `if(text != null && text.anyproperty != null)` ... so, this way, if `text != null` fails, the `text.anyproperty != null` will not be evaluated and you won't get the TypeError.

For the purpose of your validation, using `if(text != null && text.anyproperty != null)` you can achieve your goal, since if `text` is `null`, it doesn't make any sense check `text.anyproperty` (that's why the rest of the expression, the code after `&&`, is not evaluated).

Hope this help you understand better this matter :)